# Divide aggregate over sum over columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

The following assumes postgres.

Suppose I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE object (
  object_id       SERIAL  PRIMARY KEY
  object_category integer NOT NULL CHECK(value BETWEEN 1 AND 5)
);
```

I can count of the number of objects in each category using:

```
SELECT object_category,
       count(object_category) number_of_objects,
  FROM object
 GROUP BY object_category;
```

, but how can I find the ratio of the number of objects in each category to the total number of objects? For example, if the above query returns the following result set:

```
object_category | number_of_objects
-----------------------------------
              1 |                 5
              2 |                 3
              3 |                 7
              4 |                 2
              5 |                10
```

, how can I return:

```
object_category | object_ratio
------------------------------
              1 |        0.185
              2 |        0.111
              3 |        0.259
              4 |        0.074
              5 |        0.370
```

I've tried computing the sum over the above as a subquery, but I can't get access to the `number_of_objects` because postgres is complaining about missing group-by clauses, which I don't quite understand. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use window functions:

```
SELECT object_category, COUNT(*), COUNT(*) * 1.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER ()
FROM object
GROUP BY object_category;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [WINDOW FUNCTIONS](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/).

```
WITH OBJECTT
     AS (SELECT
               1 OBJECT_CATEGORY 
         UNION ALL
         SELECT
               1 OBJECT_CATEGORY 
         UNION ALL
         SELECT
               1 OBJECT_CATEGORY 
         UNION ALL
         SELECT
               1 OBJECT_CATEGORY 
         UNION ALL
         SELECT
               1 OBJECT_CATEGORY 
         UNION ALL
         SELECT
               1 OBJECT_CATEGORY 
         UNION ALL
         SELECT
               5 OBJECT_CATEGORY 
         UNION ALL
         SELECT
               5 OBJECT_CATEGORY 
         UNION ALL
         SELECT
               4 OBJECT_CATEGORY 
         UNION ALL
         SELECT
               4 OBJECT_CATEGORY 
         UNION ALL
         SELECT
               4 OBJECT_CATEGORY 
         UNION ALL
         SELECT
               2 OBJECT_CATEGORY 
         UNION ALL
         SELECT
               3 OBJECT_CATEGORY 
         UNION ALL
         SELECT
               2 OBJECT_CATEGORY 
         UNION ALL
         SELECT
               6 OBJECT_CATEGORY )
SELECT DISTINCT
       OBJECT_CATEGORY,
       COUNT (*) OVER (PARTITION BY OBJECT_CATEGORY) / COUNT (*) OVER () AS RATIO
  FROM OBJECTT
```